# How is slug being created in Sylius?

Tags: slug, sylius

I want to create new product in Sylius. I just tested:

```
$user = $this->getUser();
    $repository = $this->container->get('sylius.repository.product');
    $manager = $this->container->get('sylius.manager.product'); // Alias for appropriate doctrine manager service.

    $product = $repository->createNew();

    $product
        ->setName('Test product')
        ->setDescription('Des Product 2')
        ->setPrice(90)
        ->setUser($user)    
    ;

    $manager->persist($product);
    $manager->flush(); // Save changes in database.
```

But it trigger an exception of slug. When I try $product->getSlug(), that returns empty. I don't know how does slug created in Sylius and where is the code for that?

Answer (score 1):

It's a `gedmo:slug`, check `ProductBundle\Resources\config\doctrine\model\ProductTranslation.orm.xml`

Make sure you have a default locale configured and add this to your code:

```
      $product->setCurrentLocale($locale);
      $product->setFallbackLocale($locale);
```

Products are translatable, and I think this is what you're missing.

Check how a product is created in `Sylius\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadProductsData` line 404.